# Packaging and Reusing Aurelia View ViewModel Components

Tags: aurelia, jspm

I have a basic widget (`widget.js`, `widget.html` and `widget.css`) that I am using via a template:

```
<template>
  <require from="./widget"/>
  <widget/> 
</template>
```

**What steps do I need to take to reuse this component across aurelia projects?**

I've not made a package before, but my understanding would be to simply commit widget.js, widget.html and widget.css to a github repository, then define a JSPM package for it. I know I can define main="widget.js", but I'm not sure if I can also package the html file. Nor do I know if aurelia can "require" a template from a jspm package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reuse components like this you can create an Aurelia plugin.  A plugin is basically some re-usable piece that can be a single code-base shared across applications.

You can start your plugin from this skeleton -

https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-plugin

In a nutshell all you need to do is download the plugin source code and replace the `hello-world.js` and `hello-world.html` with your custom code in the src folder.

`index.js` is where the plugin's configure method is implemented.  This is where you will make it available to the consumers.  Typically, most plugins use `globalizeResources` so that you can prevent the consumers from having to `require` it in every view that it is used, but that is up to you since it's your plugin :)